# How do use awk along with a command to show the process ID with the 'ps' command

Tags: awk, ps

I am able to to show the `PID` (2nd column) with the below command:

```
ps -ef | grep runner | awk {'print$2'}
2432
6346
6348
6350
6352
7407
7410
7416
10824
17305
17494
29658
```

But instead I want to show `pwdx <PID>` and also the `COMMAND` (8th column).

How can I do this?

Comment: What is your real question?

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using awk to filter ps output, use the ps -o option to get what you want:

```
ps -e -o pid,comm
```

That should do what you describe above.  See the ps man page for more things to print out.

UPDATE: I see I've failed to use `pwdx`.  Try this on for size:

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -o pid= -o comm= |
while read LINE
do
    eval $(echo $LINE |
    awk '{pid=$1; comm=$2; printf "echo -n \"%s  \"; pwdx %s\n", comm, pid}' )
done
```

You may need to add flags to `ps` to get processes you want - the above only shows you your user ID's processes.

Comment: The current directory (pwdx) is not part of the available columns with some if not all ps implementations.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to print col 2 and 8 you just add $8 to the print.

```
ps -ef | grep runner | awk {'print $2" "$8'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
pwdx $(ps -ef | grep runner | awk {'print$2'})
```

alternate syntax:

```
pwdx `ps -ef | grep runner | awk {'print$2'}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The following both work for me:

```
ps -ef | grep runner | awk {'print$2'} | xargs pwdx
```

and

```
ps -ef | grep runner | for i in `awk {'print$2'}`; do pwdx $i; done
```

FYI, you will get one that looks like: `3516: No such process` which will correspond to your `grep runner` that will have completed by the time `pwdx` is called. (Also, for anyone using OS X, `pwdx` isn't in the default installation.)

EDIT: I just realized that you wanted to return `COMMAND`, too.  This will show all three on one line for each process matching `runner`:

```
ps -ef | grep runner | for i in `awk {'print$2'}`; do echo `ps -e -o pid,comm | grep $i` `pwdx $i | awk {'print$2'}`; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pwdx $(pgrep -f runner)|tr -d : > /tmp/1
pgrep -fl runner > /tmp/2
join /tmp/[12]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -e -o pid,comm | 
while read pid cmd; do 
  printf "%s %s %s\n" $pid $cmd "$(pwdx $pid| cut -d " " -f 2-)"
done
```

You might get some directories "No such process" if the process ends before pwdx is invoked for it.